# How to get rid of this conflict situation in my Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Under **config/initializers/**, I have one ruby file which will **load the id of my default** "**car**" instance from database. So, that after my application started up, my application can directly use this default car id.

**BUT**, I need to **firstly** insert this default car into databasae, so, I need either a **rake** (seed) task or alternatively a database **migration** to store the default car to database Cars table.

Here comes the **CONFLICT**! If I run rake task or migration to insert instance to database, the initializer files will **always** be run **FIRSTLY** before anything run, which means the ruby file under "**config/initializers/**" will get **nil** id of default car, because the default car has **NOT YET** been stored in database.

So, how to get rid of this conflict? (The purpose of having that initializer file is to load default car id **only ONCE**) Is there any other way to load the default car id only once?

**-------------Edit----------**

code under initializers:

```
default_car=Car.where({:name => DEFAULT_CAR_NAME})
def default_car_id
  return {:default_car_id=>default_car.id}
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you use inside the initializer please?

Comment: I added my initializer code, check my updated post.

Comment: You could create the car in the initializer instead of doing where, but this seems a little messy. When and how do you call default_car_id?

Comment: Currently, I will use default_car_id inside my methods in Car model, well, since it will also be used in all other models so I am considering to load it only once...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it like that - it seems quite messy. A single database query isn't very expensive, so I'd do something like this in your Car model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.default_car
    @default_car ||= Car.where(:name => DEFAULT_CAR_NAME)
    @default_car
  end

end
```

Would probably be a good idea to put the DEFAULT_CAR_NAME in a yaml config file if it's going to be changed at all, otherwise I'd just hardcode it.